# Java multithreading incrementation can be negative?

Tags: java, concurrency

I write simple thread-safe component, which is measuring performance of multithreading application, similar to Java profiles tools.  The idea is n-level tree of nodes,  each node is a statistics of  an invoked method of the profiling application and located in a level and under corresponding parent accordingly to execution tree. The statistics has few counters one of them is number of calls,  which is incrementing by each tread when the method invoked. At this moment I not care much regarding tread safety, so the counters has just simple long type and incrementation done by operator ++. Below I placing a code example. 
Now the question : after few hours of application work some counters become negative.  Any idea how it can be, even if some treads increments same counter at same time? 
It happens under Java 7 of IBM in RAD environment. I've ran similar application under Oracle's Java 8, it not happens.

```
class Node<T>{
Node parent; 
  Map<T, Node> children = new ConcurrentHashMap<T, Node>();
Stats stats = new Stats();
Node(Node parent) { this.parent = parent;  }
void checkIn(){ stats.checkIn(); }
void checkout(){ stats.checkout(); }
}
class Stats{
  long start, time, calls; 
  void checkIn(){ ...  calls++;}
  void checkout(){ ... }
}
class ExecutionTree<T>{
     static Map<Long, ExecutionTree> inst = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ExecutionTree>();
    Node<T> currentNode; 
static  ExecutionTreeProfiler getInstance(){
    return inst.get(Tread.currentTread().getId());
}
void checkIn(T key){ 
  // actual code is more thread-safe, but I wrote here for simplyfy it as not relevant to question
   Node<T> child =
  currentNode.children.contains(key)? 
  currentNode.children.get(key) :new Node<T>(current node);

  currentNode.children.put(key, child); 
   child.checkin();
   currentNode = child; 
}
void checkout(T key) {
   current node.checkout();
   currentNode = currentNode.parent; 
}
≠======== measuring application ========
...
void someMethod1(){
  ExecutionTree.getInstance().checkIn("method1");
.....
ExecutionTree.getInstance().checkOut();
}
…someMethod2() ...
```

Comment: The value could role over into negative after reaching its max value

Comment: Thank you for the answer, thats right, but logically it seems not the case, anyway supposing to be checked farther if no other explanation will be found, therefore I asked if other reasons could be.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - The maximum long value is 2^63-1. It's unlikely that it would roll over with individual increments. Assuming increments happen at the wildly rapid rate of 1 billion (~2^30) a second, starting from 0 it would take about 2^33 seconds to roll over, which is a considerable fraction of the current age of the universe.

Comment: Well you know with those new quantum CPUs... ;)

Comment: Nemo, did you try declaring `calls` to be an `AtomicLong` and using `calls.incrementAndGet()` instead of  `calls++`?

Comment: Ted, I didn't try Atomics, the profiling process is taking about ~5 hours tilll negatives appears, so I able to leave an one test per night, and currently my company suspended the project, therefore I can only be curious about the case and can't perform more testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you *have* to care about thread safety when doing multi-threaded programs. Incrementing a long with the ++ operation is not an atomic operation nor thread-safe... Go for the `AtomicLong` and `incrementAndGet()` that Ted Hopp suggests in the comments...

Comment: Per Huss, thanks for answer, but I care is for regular primitives there is a case to be a negatives even it is not thread-safe, but the operations are only incrementing, thats what I'm interesting to know. How to get correct number is another question which not bothering me at this moment.

Comment: @Nemo: Yes, it looks odd that it gets negative, but thing is, once you start using non-thread-safe code concurrently, all bets are off. One would need to know all nitty-gritty details on how the increment is implemented for your JVM/OS/CPU to figure out why it happens... Did you for example know that a simple HashMap get() method call can get stuck in an infinite loop if you use your hash map concurrently without proper protection?

Comment: Per Huss, first of all my question is not about bets(I know you used an idiom, but it is very good example to look at it word by word in our case), but if one case exists which can be explained by AMP processor architecture which has my Intel I7. And my question was exactly - is some nitty-gritty details on how the increment is implemented can create such situation,exactly for that I wrote a my JVM implementation and environment. I not knew about hashmap's get() infinitive loop, but being looked at the code I see a reason why it can be.